# Oracle Database Changing row value using fetch

Tags: php, oracle

The row in my database is not changing even though it is able to call from that row just not write to it

```
<?php
    $formId = $_POST["formId"];
    $newSuper = $_POST["newSuper"];
    $return = $_POST;

    require_once('mcl_Oci.php');
    $xdm = new mcl_Oci("xdm");

    $sql = "SELECT x.*,x.ROWID FROM INTOXDM.ASTP_FORM x WHERE x.FORMID = '".$formId."'";

    while($row = $xdm->fetch($sql)){

        $row['SUPERVISOR_EID'] = $newSuper; 

    }

    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to update a row in your database? So you'll need an `UPDATE` SQL statement.

Comment: Could you post an example update sql statement

Comment: No, please first tell us what you want to do ;-) You have to specify your question.

Comment: If you want to update the records in your database, you'll need something like: "UPDATE INTOXDM.ASTP_FORM SET SUPERVISOR_EID = '".$newSuper."' WHERE FORMID = '".$formId."'";

Comment: how do i execute that statement ?

Comment: By using your `mcl_Oci` class. Please read the documentation to get more information. I'm not familiar with Oracle database connections.